# Difference between IOperationBehavior and IContractBehavior?

Tags: wcf, wcf-extensions

I want to know what is difference between `IOperationBehavior` and `IContractBehavior` and what is special case when we can see difference between this two in development.

Comment: Hmm.... `IContractBehavior` is a behavior that applies to the **whole** contract (**all** operations), while a `IOperationBehavior` can be set on invidiual operations (and left out from others)

Comment: Means IContractBehavior applies to all operation then How it is diffrence from IServiceBehavior.

Comment: Same again: the `IServiceBehavior` applies to the **entire** service (**ALL** contracts - and yes, it could be multiple! - that the service class implements!) while the `IContractBehavior` applies only to one, single contract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WCF service can has [multiple contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

- [IServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) - applies to all contracts and can be applied thru the config file or the attribute
- [IContractBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.icontractbehavior.aspx) - applies only to one contract and can be applied only thru the attribute